# Duplicate Error Creating war in Unix

Tags: java, unix, jar, war

I am trying to create a war file in unix using the command "jar cfv warfile.war * ." and getting an "index.jspjava.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry" error.  When I search on the file it flags as a duplicate, I do find that same file twice, but in different directories.  Is there an option or something I'm missing to maintain the directory structure like winzip has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have both * (all files in this directory) and . (the current directory).  You either want:

jar cfv warfile.war .

or

jar cfv warfile.war *